# Call to QCursor::setPos in QML Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, qcursor

The QCursor class of Qt has as public static method called 'setPos'; I want to use this method in QML Javascript. So the question is quite straight forward: **How to call this 'setPos' method from QML Javascript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't, as there's no QML `QCursor` equivalent and `QCursor` itself does not derive from `QObject`.

But you can make a simple custom class deriving from `QObject` that just calls the `QCursor` static methods from methods marked as `slots` or `Q_INVOKABLE`.  To get out of having to create an object every time you want to call `setPos(..)`, you can [register your class](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType) as a singleton with the QML engine.